# Pine Script: how could i add a short position to this script?

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

```
``//@version=4
strategy(title="Take profit (% of instrument price)", overlay=true, pyramiding=1)

// STEP 1:
// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)



FastPeriod = input(title="Fast MA Period", type=input.integer, defval=9, minval=1, group="Moving Average")
SlowPeriod = input(title="Slow MA Period", type=input.integer, defval=50, minval=1, group="Moving Average")



TP1Perc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.5, group="TP & SL") 
TP2Perc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1, group="TP & SL") 
SLPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.5, group="TP & SL")

TP1_Ratio = input(title="Sell Postion Size % @ TP1", type=input.float, defval=50, step=1, group="TP & SL", tooltip="Example: 50 closing 50% of the position once TP1 is reached")/100


// Calculate moving averages
fastSMA = ema(close, FastPeriod)
slowSMA = ema(close, SlowPeriod)

// Calculate trading conditions
enterLong  = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)
enterShort  = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)

// Plot moving averages
plot(series=fastSMA, color=color.green, title="Fase MA")
plot(series=slowSMA, color=color.red, title="Slow MA")

// STEP 2:
// Figure out take profit price
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

percentAsPrice(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? ((pcnt / 100.0) + 1.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na)
 
current_position_size = abs(strategy.position_size)
initial_position_size = abs(valuewhen(strategy.position_size[1] == 0.0, strategy.position_size, 0))   
    
TP1  = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP1Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
TP2  = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP2Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
SL   = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(SLPerc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)



// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong) 
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)  



// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="Long", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP1, stop = SL)
    strategy.exit("TP2", from_entry="Long", limit = TP2, stop = SL) 
    
    
    
// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? TP1 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Take Profit 1")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? TP2 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title=" Take Profit 2")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? SL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Stop Loss")
`
`
```

i tried to add a short postion but when ever i go to adjust the SL and TP of the short even if i did put if strategy.position_size < 0 nothing seems to happen or change. please help me out. i did the exact same for the short condition but changed TP1 to TP1_S and all of those parameters to identify when i edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)  

if (enterShort) 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1_LONG", from_entry="Long", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP1, stop = SL)
    strategy.exit("TP2_LONG", from_entry="Long", limit = TP2, stop = SL) 
    
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1_SHORT", from_entry="Short", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP1, stop = SL)
    strategy.exit("TP2_SHORT", from_entry="Short", limit = TP2, stop = SL)
```

Comment: if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1 short", from_entry="short", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio_S, limit = TP1_S, stop= trailingActivate== true ? tsp : SLS, qty_percent = 50)
    strategy.exit("TP2 short", from_entry="short", limit = TP2_S, stop= trailingActivate== true ? tsp : SLS, qty_percent = 50)

Comment: did it like this and plotted TP1_s and TP2_S, they are being plotted correctly but no TP for short is working, position is not exiting at tp for short and idk why